# Add Spring JDBC support based on annotations

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have task to upgrade `Map` based storage to DB based storage. My project configuration is based on annotations. Could you explain to me which steps should I take to make it happen? And how will change my `dao` layer code:

```
public class TicketDao {

    Set<Ticket> tickets = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Ticket> getAll() {
        return tickets;
    }

    public void remove(Ticket ticket){
        tickets.remove(ticket);
    }

    public void put(Ticket ticket){
        tickets.add(ticket);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use Spring's JDBC template?

Comment: Yes, I do want use

Comment: Where are the annotations?

Comment: Sounds like it's not what you want but I would look at using the Spring CRUD repository b/c it would be a lot less code to write http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create db and schema
2. Configure `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate`. The simpliest configuration:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class JdbcConfig {

       @Bean
       public DataSource dataSource(){
           DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

           dataSource.setDriverClassName("");
           dataSource.setUrl("");
           dataSource.setUsername("");
           dataSource.setPassword("");

           return dataSource;
       }

       @Bean
       public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
           return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
       }

   }
   ```
3. Inject `JdbcTemplate` into dao and use it

   ```
   public class TicketDao {

       public static final String DELETE_QUERY = "delete from Ticket where id = ?";
       public static final String INSERT_QUERY = "insert into Ticket values(?, ?)";
       public static final String GET_ALL_QUERY = "select * from Tickets";

       @Autowired
       JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

       public Set<Ticket> getAll() {
           return new HashSet<>(jdbcTemplate.query(GET_ALL_QUERY, new RowMapper<Ticket>() {
               @Override
               public Ticket mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                   Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
                   ticket.setId(rs.getString(1));
                   //other fields mapping
                   return ticket;
               }
           }));
       }

       public void remove(Ticket ticket){
           jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
               @Override
               public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                   PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(DELETE_QUERY);
                   statement.setString(1, ticket.getId());

                   return statement;
               }
           });
       }

       public void put(Ticket ticket){
           Object[] values = {ticket.getId(), ticket.getName()};
           int[] types = {Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};

           jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_QUERY, values, types);
       }
   }
   ```